# Close progress dialog failed

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm trying to close a `ProgressDialog` after a couple of seconds (only visual theme) but with no success. To dismiss the dialog, I expect the Enter key to be clicked, but the dialog is always visible even when the click is done in the event. Here is the code I am using:

```
lectura.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
   public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyevent) {
      if(pDialog == null) {
           pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ValidacionBlueTooth.this);
           pDialog.setMessage("Sincronizando...");
           pDialog.setCancelable(false);
           pDialog.show();
      }

      if ((keyevent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
          pDialog.dismiss();
      }

      Intent intent = new Intent(ValidacionBlueTooth.this, Validador.class);
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

**EDIT**

I get this message that prevents the dialogue is closed and also to continue running the code.

```
01-27 16:11:31.041: W/ViewRootImpl(6633): Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_3, scanCode=4, metaState=0, flags=0x28, repeatCount=0, eventTime=81457114, downTime=81457113, deviceId=36, source=0x101 }
```

Comment: The code is odd. Why would you create a new progress dialog and show it whenever the user presses a key? Seems like you should be creating your dialog elsewhere (not in the key listener) and keep a reference to it without creating a new one each time.

Comment: Let me explain. I'm reading QR codes with a Bluetooth device. I read everything I leave on a EditText, each time the device finishes reading a code simulates the pressure of the enter key. Then, when the user reads a code with the device, I need to deploy a loader, because reading the text can be very short or very long and that will take time and when you finish reading and writing within the EditText, book reading and I use. @GeorgeMulligan

Comment: That is odd so your `Validador` activity is never shown? You might being doing something wrong elsewhere in your code. Is your activity currenlty running and visible when the key is pressed because I know you said the key press is simulated. This is the comment from Android source for when that message is printed: "This is a focus event and the window doesn't currently have input focus or has stopped. This could be an event that came back from the previous stage but the window has lost focus or stopped in the meantime."

Comment: Dear, identify the problem. We and also identify in your code when a key is pushed in the event OnKey immediately launched the dialog but below the device reading QR codes and type in the EditText is still writing so this problem occurs and stops working . It is writing while there is already an ongoing activity that is the Dialog. I think my logic is bad and I'll have to find another way to create this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class method outside of keyListener. Then inside the key listener, dismiss the progress dialog.

```
lectura.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyevent) {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ValidacionBlueTooth.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Sincronizando...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show()

    if ((keyevent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            dismissDialog();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(ValidacionBlueTooth.this, Validador.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void dismissDialog() {
     pDialog.dismiss();
}
```